# How to run any process from /dev/console?

Tags: console, devices

I want to run any simple process e.g.

```
./test.sh
```

which is printing date, but on `/dev/console` instead of `/dev/ttyN` or `/dev/pts/N`.

How do I run this program on to `/dev/console`?

Please Help...

Comment: Do you just need the output redirected or the input too?

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
./test.sh > /dev/console
```